# Which DataSet creation technique is faster?

Tags: c#, dataset

Which one of these techniques is faster?

### 1)

```
DbDataAdapter dataAdapter = _factory.CreateDataAdapter();
dataAdapter.SelectCommand = _command;

dataSet = new DataSet();

dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

### 2)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

IDataReader iDataReader= _command.ExecuteReader();

dt.Load(iDataReader);

iDataReader.Close();
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to test this yourself with your own data?

Comment: What's stopping you trying it yourself? If it's not worth your time to properly benchmark, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Jay is suggesting you try both and time them, using some data which is appropriate for the situation you're interested in.

Comment: I am actually talking about generally all cases.

Comment: OK. I can do it. I was actually probing for your experiences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these links

[DataReaders, DataSets, and performance](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030205.asp)

and

[DataAdapter.Fill preferable to DataReader?](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/DataAdapterFillPreferableToDataReader.aspx)

As mentioned in the comments to your question. It would be best to test for the given situation at hand, there is never a one rule applies to all.

Comment: I didn't know that the seniors are browsing this site at Sundays.